# Insulating JST-PH solder points

Tags: batteries, soldering, lipo, insulation

Shown in the image are the solder points corresponding to the two terminals of a JST-PH connector. (Jumper is there as a size reference). They are way too close for comfort for me, especially with potentially catastrophic consequences of shorting a LiPo. How can I reliably insulate them?
[image]

Comment: When I need the best plastic strength insulator that wont come off easily, I use Polyurethane (PU) subfloor adhesive. You might leave a sliver edge below the bump of PU for test points on the outside. allow a day to harden and 3 full strength.  But if you’re impatient any 5 minute epoxy may work but less adhesion. Kapton tape is the goto solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dab of hot glue or super glue or liquid electrical tape. Or Kapton tape.

Acrylic Nail polish works. So does your typical clear coat spray paint. A dab of 2 part epoxy also protects.

Or go for the real deal Conformal Coating spray. Expensive and meant for production instead of a one off board.

Comment: I'm not sure about conductivity of glue: Should apply it separately to the two spots or can it be one large drop that covers both spots?

Comment: None of these are conductive. You can test by putting a bit on something and use a multimeter to measure resistance.